# Does "Magna Carta" take the definite article?

Tags: definite-article

> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magna_Carta
>
> "Constitutionally, **the** Magna Carta of Edward I is the most important". This version remains in Statute today (albeit with ...

Does "Magna Carta" take the definite article?

Answer (score 6):

It’s ***the*** Magna Carta in that context, because it refers to Edward I’s reissue of it. In other contexts, practice will vary. A quick search of the Oxford English Dictionary shows 80 instances of *Magna Carta*, but only four are preceded by *the*. The British National Corpus has 47 records for *Magna Carta*, of which 11 include the definite article. Records in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, on the other hand, show a much higher proportion of records for ***the*** Magna Carta.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does.  Just like the names of organizations, committees, political parties, associations, foundations, or clubs, the names of treaties or agreements take the definite article *the*.  Other examples are *The Dayton Accords, The Kyoto Protocol* and *The Comprehensive Nuclear-Test-Ban Treaty.*